# laravel put html in a tag with blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I have this code in my view:

```
{{ HTML::linkRoute('login', 'Sign In', array(), array('class' => 'btn')) }}
```

The result is:

```
<a href="http://your.url/user/login" class="btn">Sign In</a>
```

However, I would like the result to be:

```
<a href="http://your.url/user/login" class="btn">
    Sign In <i class='ff'></i> profile
</a>
```

So my question is how to do that in laravel?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution myself, which is:

```
<a href="{{ URL::to('foobar') }}">
    <i class="fa fa-location-arrow"></i> profile
</a>
```